# Python set tcp send timeout

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, timeout

I'm trying to set TCP's SO_SNDTIMEO in Python.  Based on the socket documentation here (http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), it seems as though I should use setsockopt.

However, I'm having a difficult time understanding what to pass in for the third value parameter.   I'm trying to use the struct module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct), as the documentation recommends.  However, I'm not sure what struct I should actually be using to set the option.  Anyone have any thoughts?

(I've also tried passing both strings and integers for the third argument.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying C implementation expects a timeval struct, which can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html). It consists of two long ints, the first of which represents a time in seconds while the second is a time in microseconds.

According to the struct.pack [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), you can create a struct with two long fields using the format string ‘ll’, thus the following should set SO_SNDTIMEO as expected:

```
timeval = struct.pack('ll', some_num_secs, some_num_microsecs)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDTIMEO, timeval)
```